# Azure Function Sub-Folder Deployment

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-function-app

Im currently using VSCode to deploy my Azure Functions. The folder structure looks like,

[image]

"Src" folder contains the files which Im using with the function sitting inside Main. For ex:

```
 const action = require('../Src/'+ step);
```

I did this by nodejs require() and adding the following line in hosts.json.

```
"watchDirectories": [ "Src" ]
```

It all works perfectly when I run the functions locally, however when I try to deploy, only "Main" is getting deployed and "Src" is ignored!
What is the correct practice to deploy both Main and Src to Azure functions? Or am I doing something which is not allowed in Azure functions?

Comment: watchDirectories should have nothing to do with deployment.

Comment: I have do a test to deploy function app using VS Code, and Src success deploy to azure.

Comment: Src is normal folder without azure function in it?

Comment: Yes, of course. A normal folder with some normal files.

Comment: @BowmanZhu thats really strange. Im not sure why Im not able to do that. Im right clicking the parent folder and clicking on "Deploy to Function App". Anything other option?

Comment: Right click? No, I just be in the function app parent folder, and then [click this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ATBzj.png).

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AScsI.png

Comment: I think I know the difference now. I have the files sitting as normal workspace files and not as azure function project as youhave

Comment: So can you deploy the Src now?:)

Comment: @BowmanZhu I need to find a way to import that into the local project listing and then deploy. I will let you know